# SQL hashing a password

Tags: sql-server, hash, asp.net-mvc-5

I am manually importing from old data to MSSQL using SQL statement.
when i am hashing from raw text password to MVC 5 passwordHASH field in database.I get funny characters. How do i insert hash to mvc5 identity table?MVC 5 table is use nvarchar also

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'P@ssw0rd')as beforehash --looks good in result
0x6BFCC4026B5F162799A6DC8305C09DB9C1674AC616BD5C7422A45FBB6D0816AC163047C47A1F426F4F4C6B5B5042C671EABC4FDC7310FD5B183EEF59DC274604

declare @afterhash nvarchar(128)
set @afterhash=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'P@ssw0rd')
select @afterhash as afterhash --funny character if put inside a variable or insert to data base

ﱫ˄彫✖ꚙ菜쀅릝柁왊봖瑜ꐢ뭟࡭갖〖쑇ὺ潂䱏孫䉐燆볪�ၳ寽㸘姯⟜ц
```

Comment: What is the type of the field you want to insert that into? If its binary/varbinary you don't need to convert it at all, if its nvarchar (it probably should not be) and you want the hexadecimal value as a *string* use `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(130), HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'P@ssw0rd'), 1)` (changing the last argument to `2` to lose the `0x`)

Comment: nice. i tried convert method as well. but i didnt add the argument .after adding the arguement,it turn as correct output. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hashbytes` returns a `varbinary` data type, which you are trying to insert into an `nvarchar` variable.

If you don't want to store this value as binary but want the text that you can see currently you have a couple options depending on whether or not you want to keep the `0x` binary prefix:

```
declare @afterhash varbinary(500) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'P@ssw0rd')

select @afterhash as varbinaryValue
        ,convert(nvarchar(1000), @afterhash, 1) as nvarcharIncludePrefix
        ,convert(nvarchar(1000), @afterhash, 2) as nvarcharExcludePrefix
```

Output:

```
varbinaryValue         - 0x6BFCC4026B5F162799A6DC8305C09DB9C1674AC616BD5C7422A45FBB6D0816AC163047C47A1F426F4F4C6B5B5042C671EABC4FDC7310FD5B183EEF59DC274604
nvarcharIncludePrefix  - 0x6BFCC4026B5F162799A6DC8305C09DB9C1674AC616BD5C7422A45FBB6D0816AC163047C47A1F426F4F4C6B5B5042C671EABC4FDC7310FD5B183EEF59DC274604
nvarcharExcludePrefix  - 6BFCC4026B5F162799A6DC8305C09DB9C1674AC616BD5C7422A45FBB6D0816AC163047C47A1F426F4F4C6B5B5042C671EABC4FDC7310FD5B183EEF59DC274604
```