# SQL Server - How to insert a hashed password to a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, passwords

Sorry for my ignorance, but I want to store hashed password in my database,
How can use the `HASHBYTES` method to store hashed password in `Users` table ?

```
CREATE TABLE [Users](
    EmailAddress NVARCHAR(320) UNIQUE,
    UserID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserPassword NVARCHAR(32), -- I Edited the length
    FirstName VARCHAR(256) not null,
    LastName VARCHAR(256) not null,
    MobileNumber BIGINT,
)
```

--I checked and found this is how to hash a password

```
declare @afterhash varbinary(256) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'P@ssw0rd')
```

But how do I combine them both ?

Comment: I don't really follow. Apart from that you've defined `UserPassword` as a `varchar(16)`, so a `varbinary(8000)` is never going to fit, what are you struggling with here?

Comment: @Larnu Hi here again, I'm struggling of how to hash the password at the first insert, should it be in a separate function that invoked when the user data is passed from the client side ? I mean what if I do the `INSERT INTO` statement here ?

Comment: Just include the `HASHBYTES` as part of your `INSERT` in your parametrised statement. Again, I don't understand what the problem is here, other than the column `UserPassword` isn't fit for purpose (as it's too small)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL hashing a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853050/sql-hashing-a-password)

Comment: @Larnu Why a 16 chars length password is too short here ? should it be `NVARCHAR` ?

Comment: @LizoMatala no, its a different question.

Comment: `HASBYTES` returns a `varbinary(8000)` @ExtraSun . How do you suppose you you fit a value that is up to 8000 bytes in size in a column that is defined as only up to 32 bytes in size?

Comment: @Larnu Sure my bad, thanks, I fixed this in my question. but I still dont understand in my code is `varbinary(500)`

Comment: `@afterhash` is a `varbinary(500)` @ExtraSun . That doesn't change the data type that  returned from `HASHBYTES`... Read it's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)...

Comment: @Larnu I see there the password is  `NVARCHAR(32)` --  `CREATE TABLE dbo.Test1 (c1 NVARCHAR(32))`

Comment: In addition to previous comments, `UserPassword VARCHAR(8000)` is for storing characters. `HASHBYTES` returns `varbinary` data, the length of which depends on the hashing function chosen. e.g.: `SHA2_256` returns `varbinary(32)` because 256 bits is 32 bytes.

Comment: ... In the documentation the **unhashed** value is being store, @ExtraSun , not the hashed value. And it's not a password in the documentation, just a value to be hashed.

Comment: Personally I don't think the password should be passed in plain-text to the server at all. Hash it client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, I don't understand the problem here. Just use `HASHBYTES` in your parametrised `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (EmailAddress, UserPassword, FirstName, LastName, MobileNumber)
VALUES(@EmailAddress, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@Password), @FirstName, @LastName, @MobileNumber);
```

*Side Note: As I mentioned in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541787/compound-primary-key-issue-with-foreign-key/68542539?noredirect=1#comment121135245_68542539), `bigint` isn't the right choice for a telephone number. Phone Numbers can start with a `0` and contain other characters from digits. A value like `'01234567890'` would be changed to `1234567890`, a number like `'+441234567890'` would be changed to `441234567890`, and a number like `'(01234) 567890'` would fail to `INSERT` completely*

Comment: Adding that password  hashes should be [salted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985708/t-sql-salted-passwords) as a general security best practice.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman, but I don't understand why the need for extra complexity at `Cast(@Password As varbinary(100)`, and what's for the `Cast('|' As binary(1)) `  ? in the link you attached.

Comment: @ExtraSun, the purpose of a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is to provide additional defense because the hash will differ even for the same password (assuming a random salt). The additional complexity is small.

Comment: Thanks, @DanGuzman for credit card number I read it common to use the `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`,  do you think I should use it ? (it's not for real site just for practice)

Comment: That is a very different question, @ExtraSun , and not on topic for the comments on an answer about a different problem. Though, questions on the "best" ways to store sensitive information could be off-topic for [so] as it generate opinionated answers.

Comment: IMHO, it's best to encrypt in the client rather than SQL Server. This provides an extra security layer because the keys are not stored on the db server so not even a DBA can decrypt the value. SQL Server [Always Encrypted ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine) facilitates this.

Comment: @ExtraSun please ask a new question, ensuring it's on-topic for [so]. The comments aren't for such discussions.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, roger roger - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547730/the-best-and-safest-whey-to-encrypt-a-credit-card-number-database-or-client-si

Comment: @DanGuzman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547730/the-best-and-safest-whey-to-encrypt-a-credit-card-number-database-or-client-si

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to encrypt the password? Or is the hashing (relatively) sufficient in your opinion? I'm thinking of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Why would the OP need to be able to decrypt their user's passwords, @KonradViltersten ?

Comment: @Larnu That's a very good question. I have no good answer to that. Somehow, it felt reasonable to push the encryption into that situation. However, the more I think about it, the more it's apparent that hashing is (as a non-reversable operation) sufficient.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. You hash (and salt) the password in the database, @KonradViltersten . Then, when the user tries to authenticate, you hash and salt that password again (using the same algorithm and salt value) and compare that value to the one in the database. If they match, then the authentication is successful. The password itself doesn't need to be available in a unhash/unencrypted format here, as that is actually a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

declare @Users table (passwordColumn NVARCHAR(32));

insert @Users values (HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','Password@1234.'));

select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', passwordColumn) from @Users;